# Print archive (jar) the log is coming from in logback

Tags: java, logback

I have some descrepency between class implementations on a Tomcat server and a Websphere server.  Is there a way in logback to display the jar and version next in every log? So the log would look like this:

```
DEBUG | 2015-01-22 16:13:49.252 [Default Executor-thread-7] ApplicationName org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo - Canonicalized SignedInfo: [wss4j.jar 1.6.17]
```

My current pattern is this:

```
<pattern>%-5level | %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %contextName %logger - %message%n</pattern>
```

My POM:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.30</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest examining the full classpath of the Java process, you can simply use

```
jinfo [pid]
```

You'll get plenty of output, including `java.class.path` with all the jars and what order they are in

It's been a fairly common problem with large app servers (WebSphere, etc.) that have some other version of a library that shows up on the classpath first that you may not be expecting

Comment: Can I add that into the pattern?  Or is that similar to a server argument used in Tomcat?  If it's a server argument, do you know how to use it in websphere? Thanks for your response!

Comment: It's a separate command altogether.  You can use `jinfo` to inspect a already running java process with `jinfo [process id]`

Answer (score 0):

### This is easy to do with stacktraces.

To display the jar file and version for each line of stack trace with Logback :

You just have to add `packagingData="true"` as attribute of configuration tag.

Example :

`<configuration packagingData="true">
...
</configuration>`

Then you'll have something like :

> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]

See documentation there : [Enabling packaging data in stack traces](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#packagingData).
**Note** : As of version 1.1.4, packaging data is disabled by default.

### Article from James Strachan (2008)

- [better stack traces in Java with log4j - including the jar file and version number!](http://macstrac.blogspot.fr/2008/09/better-stack-traces-in-java-with-log4j.html)

Was referenced from [logback documentation here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#xThrowable).

### Pattern layout

Otherway you can also [customize](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord) your `pattern` with :

- %class
- %file
- %line
- %caller